# CSS Responsive Button

Tags: html, css, button

My website is https://www.webovo.nl. On the https://www.webovo.nl/blog/ page in the top-right corner, i have a blue 'Zoeken (Search)' Button and a search text field above it. I have made the button "width: 100% !important;", but i want the search field to be the same width as the search button. i have changed the width of the search field (input[type="search"]) into  100% !important but nothing changed.

When i change the width of my google chrome browser, i see that the button will become the same length as the search field at some point. When the browser reaches the width of a mobile phone, the button drops down to the bottom of the page and it becomes bigger then the search field again.

Where am i going wrong?
I hope u can find the solution by inspecting the elements and the source code of www.webovo.nl

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add your custom style in to stylesheet. Add this class in to your stylesheet:

```
form.search-form label { width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is solved!
The search field is in the `<label>` tag which has the styling of `display:inline-block`. You have 2 options here:

1) Either change the `display` level of that parent `<label>` to `block`

OR

2) Give that `<label>` a property of `width:100%`

Hope that helps you :-)